# Subtract the holidays between two dates

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsdate, nscalendar

I wrote a simple application that counts the days between two dates. Now I added with CoreData an entity called "groups of holiday" means a relationship that contains the date and name of the holiday. How do I make sure that dates are subtracted from the calculation? I can do it. Is this the right approach? Thanks.

Additional information about entities:
I have two entities, the first is called "groups of holiday", while the second "holiday". Between the two entities there is a relationship. For example, in "groups of holidays" you can create a group called "Italian holiday" and insert in it all the Italian holidays such as Christmas (12/25/2012) or Easter (04/09/2012) etc. I wish the dates included in the group of holidays are subtracted from the calculation. So if you ask the program to calculate how many days there are between 01/01/2012 and 31/12/2012 I would result in 364. Now, because the program does not consider the holidays put me as a result 366. I hope I was clear enough.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Substracted"?Please,provide more detailed indo of your entity

Comment: You've shown your IB files, and your data model.  Do you have some code as well?  Or did you just connect the various parts with bindings?

Comment: Hello, the part where the application is made the calculation is run by a code (first image), the TableView is managed by IB bindings (second image). Want to see the code?